# retrieving a model object from a java script

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller

I need to get a data base response(Java controller) from a java script find my code below:

```
//Controller

@RequestMapping("/updateuserdata.json")
public ModelAndView hUpdateDateUserData(HttpServletRequest pRequest, HttpServletResponse pResponse)
{   

Long iInsertID=iUsersDao.updateUser(iUser,iUserInfo.getId());       
        _logger.debug("UserID: "+iInsertID);

if (iInsertID < 0) {

modelAndView.addObject("response","KO");

}else

modelAndView.addObject("response","OK");

}

//Java script
if ($("#formRegistration .form_textfield_error").length>0) return;

    console.log($('#formRegistration').serialize());

    iLoginRequest=$.ajax({
     type: "GET",
     url: 'updateuserdata.json',
     dataType: 'json',
     cache: false,
     timeout: 3000,
     data: $('#formRegistration').serialize(),
     error: function(xhr, error){                       
            iLoginRequest=null;
            alert("Errore di connessione con il server!!!!");
     },
     success: function (data) 
     {                     
        console.log(data); 

      //  if($('#response').compareTo("OK")) ??? <- 
      //    {



      //    }else
      //    {
      //       $('#response')=="KO"
      //    }
     }
```

How I can get the response model object from javascript and use it as string?

Thnaks in advance,

Carmelo

Comment: compareTo? Is this JavaScript 6 or something?

Comment: I don't know how to do it in java script :)

Comment: `if (data == "OK")` assuming a text response
`if (data.response == "OK")` assuming a JSON response like `{ response:"OK"}`

Answer (score 0):

If you want the response as a plaintext string you shouldn't choose the json datatype for your jquery request.

Should you want to get the response as json however you should make sure the data you send from your controller is json encoded. What you get then is an object with the structure you define. You could then access it with `data.pathToYourString` where pathToYourString is the structure you defined.

Have a look at [JSON.org](http://json.org) if you are unsure what JSON is and what the structure looks like.